# Launching taskbar apps with AutoHotKey

Tags: windows-8, autohotkey

Windows 8 allows you to launch/minimize/restore applications in the taskbar with Win+.

I'd like to mimic this exact behaviour using the numpad instead, but I couldn't find how to reference to the applications in the taskbar: searching for it gives me tons of unrelated results, people aiming to do stuff with the taskbar, not concerning launching applications.

"Just remapping" the keys, like @MCL suggested, gives a weird result: `#Numpad2::#2` actually behaves like win+shift+2, instead of the plain win+2, which has a different behaviour (i.e. if the app is already open, it will open a new window instead of minimizing the active one).

No clue why it does that.

Comment: It surely would be helpful if you explained *how* you do it manually.

Comment: @MCL I'm not sure what you are asking. Currently Windows launches/minimizes/restores taskbar program #2 if you hit Win+2. I would like to achieve the same effect using the numpad instead (obviously for every taskbar program, "2" was just an example, i.e. I do not want to specify application names).

Comment: So it seems like all you have to do is to remap `NumpadN` to `Win+N`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @MCL oh, I was thinking about a more convoluted way, but it makes sense. Unfortunately it still behaves weirdly, as I'll explain in my edit.

Comment: @MCL nvm solved, I'll explain

Comment: Try this: `#Numpad2::Send, #2`. If Numlock is off, it's `NumpadDown`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that AutoHotKey doesn't match the actual physical key, but it searches for the symbol produced by that key with the current keyboard layout.

Since my keyboard layout has the numbers in the shift position, it sent also the shift key.

I fixed that by changing the script to:

```
#Numpad1::#&
#Numpad2::#"
#Numpad3::#$
#Numpad4::#{
#Numpad5::#}
#Numpad6::#-
#Numpad7::#/
#Numpad8::#(
#Numpad9::#)
```

which matches my layout.

However it would have been a better solution to be able to match a physical key, regardless of its output.

Comment: That's pretty weird. Have you tried using `Send` instead, as I suggested in the comments? Also try out this one `#NumPad2::Send, #{2}`.

Comment: @MCL yes, it gave the same result (looking ad the edit... same result again)

Comment: Interesting. Can you name your keyboard layout, or even better, post an image?

Comment: @MCL: here it is https://github.com/Lohoris/IT4 (win branch https://github.com/Lohoris/IT4/tree/win)

Comment: I see. In this case, I think it's normal, since `0..9` don't exist as physical keys. And physical keys are the basis. In reality, you do press `WIN+&` and not `WIN+1`. Anyhow, if you want your script to work with deactivated numlock, remap the respective keynames, too. Have a look at the [key list](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

Comment: @MCL correct! A pity you can't bind physical keys, but no big deal.